# How to stop += function in java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Y keeps on going altough I set it to 0 in Y=0;

So the sprite should go from middle to 750px and then after I click on it it should go up to 650...after i click it on 650 px it should go down to 750  (and so on)

But the code is not important,what I want to know is how to stop adding +5px on Y with some function like Y.stop();  or Y.delete(); or Y.destroy();

Y +=5;

Sorry for so little code here

```
public int Y,YspriteDown,Yposition;
public boolean AppON = true;


w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

YspriteDown=h/2+50;
YspriteUp=h/2-50;




batch.begin();
if(AppON= true)
        {

            Yposition = YspriteDown + Y ;
            Y +=5;

            if(Yposition == h-50)
            {
                Y =0;
                batch.draw(Assets.sprite1, w / 2 - 16, Yposition);
            }


batch.end();
```

Comment: are Y and Yposition the same? If not, then the condition might never trigger and Y never be set to 0.

Comment: (1) Is your variable named `Y` or `Yposition`?  (2) There is not enough information here.  The way you asked it, it appears that something is happening in a loop, but I don't see a loop anywhere in your code.  So I cannot tell what you're doing or what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Clicked variable is never set to false, so your outer loop still continues, adding 5 to y until it equals 100 again, then y is set to 0, and the loop continues.

The simple fix is to change the value of the Clicked variable to false inside of your if statement.

```
if (Clicked)
{
        Y +=5;
        batch.draw(Assets.sprite1,w/2-16,Y);
        if (Yposition == 100)
        {
            Y = 0;
            batch.draw(Assets.sprite1, w / 2 - 16,h-150);
            Clicked = false;
        }
}
```

EDIT:

With your new code, you shouldn't set Yspritedown to 0, or else the loop continues like before, it needs to end at h-50 and stay there, not revert to its original position

EDIT:

With your new new code, there needs to be an inner loop that checks if the sprite is still moving, there isn't anyway to "destroy" the variable without causing a NullPointerException, so do something like this

```
while(appIsRunning){
    if(clicked){
        boolean doneMoving = false;
        y_position += 5
        if(Y_Position >= h-50){
            y_position = h-50;
            batch.draw(arg, arg, arg);
            doneMoving = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also be sure that Y and Yposition are the variables you want to be using, because at the moment Yposition is unchanged in this loop

Comment: Take another look at my code,I changed it,now you will understand more

Comment: If you could put the full class here that would make solving much quicker, rather than changing it bit by bit